# Getting data values from form in Fat-Free framework

Tags: forms, fat-free-framework

I'm migrating from codeigniter to Fat-Free (F3) and trying to get my head around the quirks.

Regarding the following form:

```
<form ACTION = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" METHOD="POST">
  <input type="text" name="theirName" value="" required="required">
    ...
```

In standard PHP I get the POST value like this:

```
$name = $_POST['theirName'];
```

Or in codeignitor:

```
echo form_open('someclass/some_method_of_someclass');
$name = $this->input->post('name');
```

How do I get data from a form in a view in f3/fatfree?

Comment: there are some useful tutorials on the web that include forms, example [blog-tutorial-with-fat-free-framework](http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2011/09/blog-tutorial-with-fat-free-framework/)

Comment: This seems to work in passing data from a route to a route:
  $f3->route('GET /form',
  function($f3){
   echo '<form name="form" action="auth" method="POST">';
  echo 'login: <input type="text" name="getData">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
                echo '</form>';



}
);
 .......................................

$f3->route('POST /auth',
function($f3)
{
echo $f3->get('POST.getData');
}
);
auth seems to be a built in method

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the model they use has 'copyFrom' feature. i suggest just using $_POST directly. However, if you validate the input in a model that just use that model in the view.

Comment: cheers Ryan somebody else has posted similar question- so added to their post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855847/mailing-a-form-fat-free-framework/23591576#23591576. I think I can underatnd the form bit; the next problem is understanding how to use $smtp = new SMTP('mail.pickaweb.co.uk',

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get it from the [Hive](http://fatfreeframework.com/base):

```
$name = $f3->get('POST.name');
```

Comment: how to you post json data with vanilla js ?

I tried this , but teh adta do not show up in the hive :

```var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
            r.open("POST", "/staticpage/update", true);
            r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            r.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
                    alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
            };
            r.send( json );```
ps: it ios a share that commenst look so ugly on a coding platfrom like this here